# Switching Keycloak Realm based on subdomain

Tags: keycloak, identity

We are using Keycloak as our authentication server behind an application server. The solution is multi-tenanted by the subdomain. We need to switch the realm automatically based on the subdomain.

Example when user visits,

- abc.xyz.com/auth/ -> `abc` realm.
- bcd.xyz.com/auth -> `bcd` realm.

This will allow us to unify the auth logic on all the other applications on the domain. any leads? We do have the capability of setting the realm as a header using our proxy.

cheers,
Thanks in advance,
Kaveen Rodigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no clear and out-of the box solution for this. Instead what I opted was to use was the Landing Page (React APP) to take a look at the subdomain and re-write the realm accordingly.